# why doesnt my jsp request.getParameter() get the data?

Tags: html, forms, jsp

ive created a form in which user will check off checkboxes, select radio buttons, and drop downs in 1.jsp...

i want to use the information from 1.jsp to determine the output of 2.jsp...

jsfiddle for 1.jsp: http://jsfiddle.net/VWczQ/

```
action="/2.jsp">
```

now in 2.jsp i have this:

```
<% if(request.getParameter("extra") != null) { %>           
    <page:cmsElement id="cmsContent" name="/otcmarkets/traderAndBroker/market-data-vendors/wizard-results" />
<% } else if(request.getParameter("all") != null) { %>
    <page:cmsElement id="cmsContent" name="/otcmarkets/traderAndBroker/market-data-vendors/con-all" />
<% } else { %>
    <h1>holy crap everything is null!!!</h1>
<% } %>
```

when i randomly choose options from the form everything is NULL...

what am i doing wrong?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be expecting that the `id` attribute of the HTML input elements is been sent as request parameter name. This is wrong. It's the `name` attribute which is been sent as request parameter name. Its value is then the `value` attribtue which is been set on the named input element.

So, instead of for example your incorrect check

```
if(request.getParameter("extra") != null) {
    // ...
}
```

for the following radio button

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="extranet" id="extra"/>
```

you need to get the parameter by name `choice` and test if its value is `extranet`.

```
if ("extranet".equals(request.getParameter("choice"))) {
    // ...
}
```

As to the `all` checkbox, I am confused. It is possible to send the *both* values, yet you're checking them in an `if-else`. Shouldn't the `all` be inside the same radio button group? Shouldn't you remove the `else`? In any way, the point should be clear. It's the input elements' `name` attribtue which get sent as request parameter name, not the `id` attribute.

Comment: o i see i should be checking for the "name" and getting the "value" not the "id"... the "all" is checkall checkbox i will use.. thanks Balus!!!

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but the logic flow as you have in your JSP would potentially result in a response which is unexpected/unintuitive to the enduser. E.g. if the enduser checks **both** the "Extra" radio button *and* the "All" checkbox, then the enduser would only get the "Extra" page, not also the "All" page.

Comment: does checking (request.getParameter("name")!=null) work? im trying that but it is still giving me null.. as for the choices, they will be disabled according to the users choices, if user clicks "extra" then 3-5 checkbox will be disabled and etc..

Comment: It will only be null if the parameter is not sent or the request has been redirected. Use a HTTP traffic tracker tool like Firebug or Fiddler to track the traffic. Use `request.getParameterMap()` to see/debug all the parameters.

Comment: do i need some sort of servlet to do this? or i can just set up 2 jsp pages and send data from one to the other?

Comment: A servlet is not necessary in order to get it to work, but it is preferred to end up with a better design. Two JSPs should work as good. Perhaps the parameter name is still not what you think or something else (JavaScript maybe?) has caused a redirect during submit. As said, using Firebug and checking content of `request.getParameterMap()` should give a lot of insights as to what is happening.