# Pass selected item from drop down list to servlet in doPost method?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working with Servlet and JSP. I have a form in which I have a drop down list which is getting populated dynamically. Now once I have selected any items from that drop down list, I want to printout that selected item in my doPost method in the servlet. In general, I need to pass selected drop down list to servlet.

Below is my doPost method -

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("hello");
    // somehow this prints out null
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("accounts"));

}
```

And below is my jsp page -

```
<form id="form_delete" method="post" action="/dataservlet/">
    <h3> Delete Existing Item</h3>

    <div class="line"><label for="accounts">Choose an existing item : </label> <select id="accounts"></select></div>

    <div class="line submit"><input type="submit" value="Delete Item"/></div>

</form>
```

Somehow from my above JSP page, whatever items I have selected in the drop down list, is not getting printed out. Anything wrong I am doing?

Comment: There's nothing in your drop down.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is getting populated dynamically. Once the page gets loaded up, I can see the values in it.

Comment: Aint you missing <option>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `name` attribute as well that will become the part of the request parameter.

It should be

```
<select name="accounts">
```

instead of

```
<select id="accounts">
```

---

> You seem to be expecting that the id attribute of the HTML input elements is been sent as request parameter name. This is wrong. It's the name attribute which is been sent as request parameter name. [(Read more)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588677/why-doesnt-my-jsp-request-getparameter-get-the-data)